I'm getting no matching distribution error when pip installing sourcedefender for a school assignment. I've tried both Python 3.8.10 and 3.10.11
I have to pip install dependencies after setting up a virtual environment for an intro python course and I'm getting an error message:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sourcedefender==10.0.13 (from versions: 12.0.2,
12.0.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sourcedefender==10.0.13
It has a requirements.txt file that contains all dependencies.
I looked on the sourcedefender release page on pypi and it doesn't have any releases listed besides 12.0.2 and 12.0.3. I installed the same dependencies for a similar assignment last week and had no issues. I've tried Python 3.10.11 (which is the version I've been using all semester) and 3.8.10.
When I put sourcedefender== 12.0.2 in the requirements.txt file, it says it needs updated versions of other dependencies, and when I edit those into the requirements.txt file, it gives an error about a NoneType and seems to just break. I'm not sure why this is happening, can someone help me?
Is it possible that they removed the sourcedefender release that I need?

I can't seem to comment as I dont have enough reputation so I will leave my answer here.
Sometimes the right answer is the most obvious one.

Someone probably made a mistake or typo.

or this version used to be hosted on pypi and was recently taken down.


Do you know what version you installed for your previous assignment?
When you installed it previously, the files might have been downloaded locally so you wouldnt have to get them from pypi.
I also looked into it and tried to install it and got this error when running pip3 install sourcedefender==10.0.13
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement sourcedefender==10.0.13 (from versions: 12.0.2, 12.0.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for sourcedefender==10.0.13

I also checked the pypi and you are right there are only 2 versions as written in the error above. You should contact your lecturer and ask them whats up.
Don't waste too much time on this.
If you are expected to solve this yourself. Then use version 12.0.2 and try to see which packages need to be upgraded and slowly change their versions until it works.

You were correct that the instructor made a mistake. The requirements.txt file simply said sourcedefender==10.0.13 when it should have said dependencies/sourcedefender-10.0.13. This is because it was nested in a folder that was downloaded for the assignment.
Thank you for reminding me that I should look for simpler mistakes before looking at higher level problems.
